# How i can handling all errors in Kohana 3.3

Tags: php, kohana

How i can handling every error in Kohana 3.3?
I means no 404/505 error but "Fatal Error" from php and others php's errors?

I looked on http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/tutorials/error-pages and i do this things, but it's handling only 404/505 errors (and others). I cant handling 500 error.

I create file
/APP/Classes/HTTP/Exception/500.php

```
class HTTP_Exception_500 extends Kohana_HTTP_Exception_500 {

    public function get_response()
    {
        $session = Session::instance();
        $view = View::factory('index');
            $view->content = View::factory('errors/505');
        $view->title = 'Wewnętrzny błąd';
        // Remembering that `$this` is an instance of HTTP_Exception_404
            $view->content->message = 'Wystąpił wewnętrzny błąd. Szczegóły zostały     przekazane do administracji, naprawimy to!';

        $response = Response::factory()
            ->status($this->getCode())
            ->body($view->render());

        return $response;
    }
```

But it dosn't work..
Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

"Custom error pages will only be used to handle throw [HTTP_Exception](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/HTTP_Exception)'s. If you simply set a status of, for example, 404 via [Respose::status()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Respose#status) the custom page will not be used." - The tutorial you linked.

The code which calls [HTTP_Exception::get_response()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/HTTP_Exception#get_response) is located in [Request_Client_Internal::request_execute()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Request_Client_Internal#execute_response).

To handle other exceptions you need to overwrite [Kohana_Exception::response()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Kohana_Exception#response). Something like this should work.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct script access.');

class Kohana_Exception extends Kohana_Kohana_Exception {

    /**
     * Generate a Response for all Exceptions without a more specific override
     *
     * The user should see a nice error page, however, if we are in development
     * mode we should show the normal Kohana error page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public static function response(Exception $e)
    {
        if (Kohana::$environment >= Kohana::DEVELOPMENT)
        {
            // Show the normal Kohana error page.
            return parent::response();
        }

        $view = View::factory('index');
        $view->content = View::factory('errors/500');
        $view->title = 'Wewnętrzny błąd';
        $view->content->message = 'Wystąpił wewnętrzny błąd. Szczegóły zostały przekazane do administracji, naprawimy to!';

        $response = Response::factory()
            ->status(500)
            ->body($view->render());

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just write this snippet in your bootstrap.php

```
if (Kohana::$environment == Kohana::PRODUCTION)
{
    Kohana_Exception::$error_view = 'template/errors';
}
```

And you can still have a different view for HTTP_Exceptions

```
<?php defined ('SYSPATH') or die ('No direct script access.');

class HTTP_Exception extends Kohana_HTTP_Exception {

    /**
     * Generate a Response for all Exceptions without a more specific override
     * 
     * The user should see a nice error page, however, if we are in development
     * mode we should show the normal Kohana error page.
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function get_response()
    {
        // Lets log the Exception, Just in case it's important!
        Kohana_Exception::log($this);

        if (Kohana::$environment >= Kohana::DEVELOPMENT)
        {
            // Show the normal Kohana error page.
            return parent::get_response();
        }
        else
        {
            // Generate a nicer looking "Oops" page.
            $view = View::factory('template/http_errors');

            $response = Response::factory()
                ->status($this->getCode())
                ->body($view->render());

            return $response;
        }
    }
}
```